# Finding Multiple Sequences in a File by Position after SpecifIcally Repeating Characters

Tags: python

i am trying to write this code, so that i can get my sequences of different samples in a file after line breaks by position, the output is always blank for some reason, can you help me?

```
import readline
count = 0
brk = 0
with open("file.txt") as f:
    while (count < 35):
        l = f.readline()[brk + 2]
        sp = raw_input ("Starting Position:")
        sp = int(sp)
        rl = sp + 6
        print(l[sp:rl])
        print(l[-30:0])
        count = count + 1
        brk = brk + 2

    print ("Done")
```

Comment: It is a loop, it will ask from me the position for 35 times, because there is 35 samples data in the file, after that it will say done. Yes file exists, if there wasnt a file, it would say so, maybe it cant report the sequence because first it has to record it, than print, also tried that one but didnt work.

Comment: So, you wrote "the output is always blank", but it was false? It is not helpful! If you need any answer, please write true in the question.

Comment: When you run it, first goes the 2nd line break in file, it asks you "Starting Position", lets say 1444th character, in print it should give sequence between 1444-1450 and -30 unit behind that particular break, but the output is blank, and than as per to loop, asks the "Starting Position" from the 4th line break which is where the next sample data is, and so on. Until 70 line breaks, says "done" because that is the number of samples in the file. We good?

Comment: It is still hard to help you. Could you simplify your program? Show us [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without opening a file (just put the proplem string into the code), without asking for input, etc.

Comment: Simply put, i need to target a specific character in a huge text, and taking that char. as origin, i want to read a specific position from that origin. I tried `read` but it doesnt work if i make `str` from these origion, since `str` dont have `read`. Think it like data conversion.

Comment: It's hard to understand your problem, consider hardcoding a sample string from the file!

Answer (score 0):

In the line `l = f.readline()[brk + 2]` the program puts one character into variable `l`. So, when you are trying to print substring of `l` (in the lines `print(l[sp:rl])` and `print(l[-30:0])`), the program prints empty lines. It is expected result.

To find this you could just add `print l` right after assigning of `l`.

It seems that you are trying to read 2-nd, 4-th, 6-th, etc lines of the file. To do it you can do something like this:

```
brk = 0
with open("file.txt") as f:
    f.readline()
    f.readline() #skip both first lines
    while (count < 35):
        l = f.readline()
        f.readline() #skip next line
        sp = raw_input ("Starting Position:")
        sp = int(sp)
        rl = sp + 6
        print(l[sp:rl])
        print(l[-30:0])
        count = count + 1
        brk = brk + 2
```

Also `print(l[-30:0])` must always print empty line. It seems that you need `print(l[-30:])` (last 30 characters of the string `l`).

Comment: `l[-30:0]` will always be blank regardless of the length of `l`, since creating a slice with `end <= start` produces the empty string. You probably want `print(l[-30:])`.

Comment: Sorry, `end <= start` is not very clear: what I mean is that a slice where `end` is *before or equal to* `start` will produce the empty string. Since nothing is *before* index 0, then this slice will always be empty.

Comment: @nelfin Thank you, I extended this answer.

Comment: "the program puts one character into variable l." hold on. doestn this function generate a string of "l" out of file "f" which consists of many lines? i wanted to segment the 2th,4th,6th...etc. lines of file into string, than read or print the desired position in those strings, but the way you explain "f.readline" only reads the first char. of particular line, than it is useless to me.

Comment: @Lindy In the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=readline#file.readline) you can find that this function reads one entire line from the file. But when you add `[brk + 2]` after it, you get only one character of this line.